# Dictionary order topology and subspace topology

Tags: general-topology

Compare $(0,1) \times (0,1)$ with the dictionary order topology to the same set with the subspace topology given by the dictionary order on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

This is an exercise in my intro topology book that I am reading. Can anyone explain this? I've been thinking about it for awhile but haven't really gotten anywhere.

The subspace topology of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is just the topology made up of intersections of some subset $Y$ and basis elements of the topology we have.

Comment: Can you find any set that’s open in one topology and not in the other? If not, try to prove that they’re actually the same topology. HINT: What do basic open nbhds of a point $\langle x,y\rangle$ look like in the two topologies?

Comment: So we have the set $(0,1) \times (0,1)$ with the dictionary order topology being compared to the set $(0,1) \times (0,1)$ with the subspace topology on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ right?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: So the dictionary order on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is given by $a \times b < c \times d$ if $a<c$ or if $a = c$ and $c < d$. So for our problem, we have the set $(0,1) \times (0,1)$. Visually, that (I think) looks like vertical lines within a $(0,1) \times (0,1)$ box. I think this is the same as the subspace topology on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, but ehh...

Comment: Your mental picture is correct, and they are indeed the same. Try showing that the set of intervals of the form $\{x\}\times(y_0,y_1)$, where $x\in(0,1)$ and $0<y_0<y_1<1$ is a base for both topologies.

Comment: I don't think i'm going to be able to get past that part. Seems a bit more complicated. I would think I have to show that $(x_0, y_0) \times (x_1, y_1)$ is a union of basis elements from the set $(0,1) \times (0,1)$ w/ the dictionary order topology and then do the same when it has the subspace topology. Though, actually doing that i'm not sure how

Comment: Why are you even considering $(x_0,y_0)\times(x_1,y_1)$? You don’t care about sets that are products of two open intervals, since the topology on $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ isn’t the Euclidean topology.

Comment: Because $(0,1) \times (0,1)$ are just the boundaries of the set isn't it? That is why we are considering points like $x$, $y_0$, and $y_1$. I'm not sure why what you wrote is any different than what I wrote

Comment: I said nothing about products of open intervals (apart from acknowledging that the space in question is the set $(0,1)\times(0,1)$. The open sets that I want you to look at are vertical line segments open at both ends.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is explained well in the comments, but I thought I would draw a few pictures to clarify things further!

Consider the dictionary order topology on $(0, \ 1) \ \times \ (0, \ 1)$, which consists of all sets of the form $(a \ \times \ b, \ c \ \times \ d)$, with $0 \ < \ x \ < \ 1$ for $x \ = \ a, \ b, \ c, \ d$ and $a \ < \ c$ or $a \ = \ c$ and $b \ < \ d$.

Now, the dictionary order topology on $\mathbb{R} \ \times \ \mathbb{R}$ behaves the same way, but consists of dictionary ordered open intervals of all real numbers. We then take the intersection of all these sets with $(0, \ 1) \ \times \ (0, \ 1)$ to get the subspace topology.

The best way to prove this is to simply visualize it. Consider the two forms of open set for the first topology we described:

[image: top1]

Then consider sets of this same form in $\mathbb{R} \ \times \ \mathbb{R}$, intersecting $(0, \ 1) \ \times \ (0, \ 1)$:

[image]

Proving this is just a matter of taking these pictures, and writing down what is visually true (the topologies are the same), in more rigorous language, which is fairly straightforward once the intuition is gained with the pictures.