# showing order topology on subspace need not be same as subspace topology obtained from order topology

Tags: general-topology

I have an assignment to show

> Showing dictionary order on topology $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ is not same as subspace topology obtained from dictionary order on $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$.

I need hints to begin. I know two topologies are same if their basis elements are same or if I can show them if either of them are finer than other simultaneously. How do I show they are different this case?

Also from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015637/dictionary-order-topology-and-subspace-topology), I have come to know that on subspace $(0, 1) \times (0, 1)$, the two topologies are same. Is my problem wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $\left\{\frac12\right\}\times\left(\frac12,1\right]$ is an open nbhd of $\left\langle\frac12,1\right\rangle$ in the subspace topology; is it open in the lexicographic order topology on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$?

Comment: is this proposition true? "A set $A$ is open in subspace $Y \subset X$ iff $A = Y \cap C$ for open set $C \subset X$."

Comment: @Santosh: Yes: in fact, that’s pretty the definition of the subspace topology.

Comment: Thanks professor!! $\{1/2\} \times (1/2, 3/2) $ is open in $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ so using the above proposition, with intersection form $[0,1]$, we get $\{1/2\} \times (1/2, 1]$ is open in subspace of $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$.

Comment: How do I show that $\{1/2\} \times (1/2, 1]$ is not closed in $[0,1]\times [0, 1]$? Perhaps I should begin with basis of lexicographic order topology on it?

Comment: @Santosh: You’re right about the subspace topology. To show that it’s not open in the lex. order top. on the square, show that every open nbhd of $\left\langle\frac12,1\right\rangle$ contains points of the square with $x$-coordinate bigger than $\frac12$. Yes, looking at basic open intervals in the lex. order topology is the right way to go.

Comment: So, are we showing $\{1/2\} \times (1/2, 1]$ cannot be neighborhood of $\langle 1/2, 1 \rangle$?

Comment: @Santosh: Yes, that’s right. And that will show that the two topologies on the square are not the same.

Comment: Thank you professor!! I understand it :)

Comment: @Santosh: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Show that $\{ 1/2 \} \times [0,1]$ is open in the subspace topology.