# Comparing topologies in plane

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I am learning Munkres's Topology on my own. I have some confusions.

Let $I = [0,1]$. Consider the following topologies

I want to prove the followings:

Let, $\mathbb{R}_d$ is $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with discrete topology. Then,

1. The product topology on $I \times I$  is strictly coarser than the topology inherits as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_d \times \mathbb{R}$.
2. The dictionary order topology on   $I \times I$ is strictly coarser than the topology inherits as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_d \times \mathbb{R}$.

My attempt for 1. : A basis element of product topology on $I \times I$ is $$((a, b) \cap [0, 1]) \times ((c, d) \cap [0, 1]) $$ and a basis element of the topology inherits as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_d \times \mathbb{R}$ is $$\{x\} \times ((c, d) \cap [0, 1])$$. We see that $$((a, b) \cap [0, 1]) \times ((c, d) \cap [0, 1]) \ = \bigcup_{x \in (a, b) \cap [0, 1]} \{x\} \times ((c, d) \cap [0, 1]) $$
Hence, open in $\mathbb{R}_d \times \mathbb{R}$. For strictness, consider $\{\frac{1}{2}\} \times (\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3})$. Clearly, $\{\frac{1}{2}\} \times (\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3})= \{\frac{1}{2}\} \times ((\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3})\cap [0,1])$., so it is open in the subspace topology, but not open in the product topology.

Am I correct so far? Please let me know if you find any wrong.

But, I can not prove 2.  Till now I have attempted for 2. :

A basis element of the order topology is $(a \times b, c\times d)$. I have written that
$$(a \times b, c\times d) = \{a\} \times (b,1) \cup \bigcup_{a<x<c} (\{x\} \times (0,1)) \cup \{c\} \times (0,d)$$ Is the above correct?

Please correct me.

Comment: #1 looks correct.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015637/dictionary-order-topology-and-subspace-topology  has a good visualization of the dictionary order, been a while since I've done topology, thinking it over myself. That basis looks slightly off for the case when $a=c$, because then you are are including all the stuff from $b$ to $1$ and $0$ to $d$ when it should be just the stuff from $b$ to $d$

Answer (score 1):

For 1: $\Bbb R_d \times \Bbb R$ contains all sets that are product open in $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ and so on the subset $I \times I$ we have the same relation, and the product topology on $I \times I$ has the subspace topology wrt the latter. The inclusion is strict because $\{0\} \times I$ is not open in the product topology on $I \times I$ but *is* open in the subspace topology from $\Bbb R_d \times \Bbb R$, e.g.

For 2: a basic neighbourhood of $0 \times 0$ in $I \times I$ (order top.) is $[0 \times 0, 0 \times b) = (\{0\} \times (-1,b)) \cap (I \times I)$. We can write similar equations for other open intervals or sets of the form $(1\times a, 1 \times 1]$, showing that the order topology on $I \times I$ is coarser than the inherited topology from $\Bbb R_d \times \Bbb R$. Strictness can be witnessed as the open set $\{\frac12\} \times I$ (inherited from $\Bbb R_d \times \Bbb R$) is not open in the order topology as $\frac12 \times 0$ is not an interior point of it.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the comment,  the first one looks fine.  The second only works as a basis for when $a<c$,  when $a=c$ then your set looks like $\{a\}\times (b,d)$ (along with the whole space as needed for a topology.

These are clearly open in the $\mathbb{R}_d \times \mathbb{R}$ topology,  as all singletons times open intervals are open, as those are the basis elements for each topology.

The converse is a bit trickier, MOST singletons times an interval are open in the dictionary order.  $\{0\}\times [0,1]$ and $\{1\}\times [0,1]$ are going to be your missing ones, as the only way to generate a singleton out of the dictionary order is if $a=c$,  and you can't get the whole interval $[0,1]$ with any choice of $b,d$, the best you can get is $b=0,d=1$ where you get $(0,1)$

Comment: Do you want to say that I should write $(a \times b, c\times d)  = \{a\} \times (b,d)$ instead of $(a \times b, c\times d) = \{a\} \times (b,1) \cup \bigcup_{a<x<c} (\{x\} \times (0,1)) \cup \{c\} \times (0,d)$?

Comment: Actually, for 2. I want to show that the basis element $(a\times b,c \times d),\  a\times b<x\times y<c \times d$ can written as the union of the basis elements of the form $\{x\} \times ((c, d) \cap [0, 1])$ . Can you write it more explicitly?